# img instead of text in listView (C#)

Tags: c#

How to do that instead of the `delete` in the `listView1` add a .png graphic?

```
ListViewItem product = new ListViewItem("delete");
product.SubItems.Add("text");
listView1.Items.Add(product);
```

Comment: Set the LargeImagelist!

Comment: Imo this is a really bad 'duplicate' as it recommends using an unnecessary library instead of the simple built-in solution..